# Doctrine to Propel snippet

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, propel

I am using the Propel ORM with SF (1.4). I am writing a class, and I need to rewrite a query Doctrine query into Propel:

```
  $q = Doctrine_Core::getTable('sfGuardRememberKey')->createQuery('r')
        ->innerJoin('r.sfGuardUser u')
        ->where('r.remember_key = ?', $cookie);

  if ($q->count()){ // Do Something }
```

can anyone help with the conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it and fix column names:

```
$c = new Criteria;
$c->addJoin(sfGuardRememberKeyPeer::USER_ID, sfGuardUserPeer::ID, Criteria:INNER_JOIN);
$c->add(sfGuardRememberKeyPeer::REMEMBER_KEY, $cookie);
$result = sfGuardRememberKeyPeer::doSelect($c);
if(count($result)) // do something
```

Comment: Fixed a simple, single typo - then it worked like a charm. tx!